# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'never' for array of data fetched through Axios

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I am using React Query to fetch an array of Todo items from this public API: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos. Once I obtain the list of Todo items, I map each item to a list in my component. Here is the code snippet:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

interface Todo {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  userId: number;
  completed: boolean;
}

const fetchTodos = () => {
  axios
    .get<Todo[]>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
    .then((res) => res.data);
};

const TodoList = () => {
  
  const { data: todos } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["todos"],
    queryFn: fetchTodos,
  });

  return (
    <ul className="list-group">
      {todos?.map((todo: Todo) => (
        <li key={todo.id} className="list-group-item">
          {todo.title}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

Currently, I VS Code is raising an error that property 'map' does not exist on type 'never'. I am also told in console that "Query data cannot be undefined". VS Code says that *todos* is type `void | undefined`. However, I don't see how this is possible when I specified type `Todo[]` as part of `axios.get()` .

[current_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt9GD.png)

I've tried to explicitly define the return type of `fetchTodos()` function with no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'never' for array of data fetched through Axios

Your `fetchTodos` function is a *void* function (does not return anything). You should add a *return* keyword to fix the issue.

```
const fetchTodos = () => {
  return axios // return value
    .get<Todo[]>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
    .then((res) => res.data);
};
```

Comment: Ah okay this was easy! Thank you.